# Finding the flow of a vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, smooth-manifolds, solution-verification, vector-fields

Consider the vector field $X=-x_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+x_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$. I want to calculate the flow of this vector field in $\mathbb R^3$.

As far I understand the calculate the flow we need to solve $X(\gamma(t))=\frac d{dt}\gamma(t)$. Let $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$. Then $X(\gamma(t))=(-y(t),x(t),0)$ and $\frac d{dt}\gamma(t)=(x'(t),y'(t),z'(t))$.
This is satisfied by $\gamma(cos(t),sin(t),0)$.

Is this calculation correct, it seem I should do something about initial conditions?

Comment: Solving that differential equation results in a so called integral curve to the vector field, if you add some initial condition. The flow is, more generally, a map $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^3\times I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $ which solves the ODE for any given initial value. So for fixed $x$, $\Phi(x,t)$ is the integral curve $\gamma(t) $ with $\gamma(0) = x$.